# Bash !$ equivalent for first word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Is there a way for Bash to return the first word of the previous command (the command name itself), similar to how `!$` returns the last word of the previous command?

For instance:

```
ls -l
```

I would like to return `ls`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose a word by number with `!:`. This includes any pre-command assignments, so the exact number you need varies.

```
$ x=3 some_command foo   # some_command is !:1
$ ls -l                  # ls is !:0
$ x=6 y=3 bar            # bar is !:2
```

Comment: Thank you. Now second question, how can I alias `!:0` to something else. `alias @@="!:0"` or `alias @@=!:0` is giving me the error -bash: !:0: command not found